# scrape star rate of site using mozenda

Tags: web-scraping

I want to scrape star rate from this site:
http://www.pixel.ir/canon/3071-canon-eos-700d-18-55-is-stm.html

I can scrape text, but star rate are shown as a image.
in its source star rate are give by radio:

```
<div class="gsrReviewLineRating" id="gsrDisplayRating1"> <input class="star" type="radio"id="gsrRating1" name="gsrRating1" value="1" /><input class="star" type="radio" id="gsrRating1" name="gsrRating1" value="2" /><input class="star" type="radio" id="gsrRating1" name="gsrRating1" value="3" /><input class="star" type="radio" id="gsrRating1" name="gsrRating1" value="4" /><input class="star" type="radio" id="gsrRating1" name="gsrRating1" value="5" **checked**="checked"/></div>
```

I tried to scrape it with mozenda, but i cant,
is there any way to scrape it?
Is there other software for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to grap `value` from `checked` `input`.

```
<input ... value="5" **checked**="checked"/>
```

I use python and `requests`, `lxml` modules:

```
import requests
import lxml, lxml.html

r = requests.get('http://www.pixel.ir/canon/3071-canon-eos-700d-18-55-is-stm.html')

html = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)

checked = html.cssselect('input#gsrAverageRating[checked]')

if checked:
    print checked[0].attrib.get('value', None)
else:
    print "No stars"
```

Comment: thanks, but i am not familiar with python, Is it possible to use this code in java?

Comment: If you have some library to work with html and CSS selector than you can use it some information in it - like `'input#gsrAverageRating[checked]'`.

Comment: Well, there is `Jython` - Python in Java. I never used it but maybe you could use it.

Comment: thanks, i will try it. i have another question, if it is possible please guide me.

Comment: i have this item in different pages, and for different product, is it possible to write a code for scraping text and its star rate from different pages and for different product?

Comment: Using `cssselector()` and other functions from `lxml` you can get other data from page. If you know urls you can put it on the list and use `for` loop. If you don't know urls but you know page with urls you can use `requests` and `lxml` to get that urls.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Mozenda pretty easily. If you copy and paste the XML below into an agent it will create the action that will capture the star rating. To figure out how to capture it from multiple pages you can go here -- http://mozenda.com/help/helptopic?TopicID=149

```
<!--- - - - - - - - Actions - - - - - - - - -->
<ActionList>
  <Action>
    <ActionType>GetElementValue</ActionType>
    <Page>1</Page>
    <FieldExpression>value=&amp;quot;%Star Rating%&amp;quot;</FieldExpression>
    <FieldExpression>value='%Star Rating%'</FieldExpression>
    <FieldExpression>value=%Star Rating% </FieldExpression>
    <FieldExpression>value=%Star Rating%&amp;gt;</FieldExpression>
    <ItemType>PlaceHolder</ItemType>
    <ItemXPath>//input[@name=&amp;quot;gsrAverageRating&amp;quot;][5]</ItemXPath>
    <ID>gsrAverageRating</ID>
    <Name>gsrAverageRating</Name>
    <FieldValueType>Outer</FieldValueType>
  </Action>
</ActionList>
```

Comment: In the list of actions in the bottom left corner. When you paste the XML, Mozenda will convert it into an action named Capture - Star Rating.